# I need some explanation on global $post

Tags: posts, query, variables, globals

Sorry if this sounds like a dumb question but it's something that has bugged me for a while. I need some explanation on

```
function custom_function () {
    global $post;
}
```

I understand from PHP that a global variable is available is used to access global variables from anywhere in the script. I know `global $post` usually set when a new query is being set. What would happens if global variable is not declared in case of WordPress query posts? I know how to use it in WordPress but have not fully understand why. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The `global $post;` command acts similar to `the_post()` function, but outside the loop.

When you want to use post's data such as `get_the_ID()` or `the_title()` and you are not in the loop, you can use the `global $post;` to access these data. After so, you can have access to them, such as `$post->ID` or `$post->post_title`. This way, you can use the above functions as follows:

```
get_the_title( $post->ID );
```

In a loop, you can use the `the_post()` function to do this:

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();
        // Now you can use the_ID(); for example
    }
}
```